# Update remote branches to my fork on github

Tags: github, fork, branch

I've seen several answers about updating the fork with the commits of the upstream, but I haven't found how to update the entire repository.

I cloned a repo into my fork, made changes, commited, pushed, done.

In the meanwhile, other branches were created, deleted, etc.

Now I want to create a branch from a new created branch in the upstream, but I can't find it on my fork's GitHub UI for example, it's still showing the old ones.

How can I update this?

I already tried to fetch the upstream, no success.

EDIT: to make it easier to understand, I will give an example:

In original repo, it has a new created branch, let's say, "fancy-new-branch"

If I type `git checkout fancy-new-branch`, it switches to this branch, but in the original repo. But I want to be in my fork, so I can create a new branch for example "fancy-new-branch-fix" from "fancy-new-branch" I think I need to access "fancy-new-branch" from my fork, or am I wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting my fork, creating and cloning again. But I will keep up the question: isn't there an automatic way to update?